# How to access vue props with name contains dash sign?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-props

I'm working on a `Vue` project. With the `eslint`'s requirement, I cannot name the props with `camel case` and it will report a warning `Attribute ':clientId' must be hyphenated. eslint vue/attribute-hyphenation` is required to use `kekab` case instead. For example,

```
<GranfFather :client-id="clientId" v-bind="$attrs">
  <Father>
    <GrandSon />
  </Father>
</GrandFather>
```

I need to access the property in the `<GrandSon />` component. Generally, I'd like to name the property as `clientId`, but due to the `eslint`'s requirement of the company, I can only name it as `client-id` otherwise it will report a warnning. So, if I want to access this property, the only method I come up with is use `this.$attrs["client-id"]`. But I'm wondering how could I access this property via `this.$attrs.clientId` or in a similar method?

when I use `this.$attrs` in `<GrandSon />` component, it print

```
{ client-id: "xxxxxx" }
```

Is this mean I can only `client-id` via `this.$attrs["clientId"]`?
What I want is access `client-id` just by using `this.$attrs.clientId`.

Comment: I believe you can just  access the prop as `clientId` inside the component as kekab  case are automatically converted to camel case ?

Comment: `client-id` is a prop. It's always normalized to camel case when it's accessed. There's no clientId or client-id prop in GrandSon because you didn't provide it to it.

Comment: Well, I currently cannot directly access the prop `clientId`. I don't know why when I use `this.$attrs.clientId`, it returns `undefined`. I can only access the prop when I use `this.$attrs["client-id"]`.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unclear what you try to achieve. If you need to provide clientId prop to GrandSon then do this explicitly. There's a difference between attributes and props. Props are normalized to camel case. Attributes aren't. It's possible for GrandSon to inherit an *attribute* if it's root element of Father, and the same is for GrandFather-Father relation. See https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html .

Comment: I have updated my description. What I want to achieve is just access the prop `client-id` in `camel` case in component `<GrandSon />`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) and [attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html?redirect=true#Non-Prop-Attributes).

A prop is supposed to be specified in component `props`, it is normalized to camel case and received only by a component that a prop was provided to.

Attributes aren't normalized and can [fall through](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html) components that are used as root elements. This behaviour is determined by `inheritAttrs` property in components. It is commonly used to provide HTML attributes to root HTML elements, but can also be used to provide a prop to nearest nested components that accept it.

If `GrandSon` is supposed to receive `clientId` prop, it needs to be declared in the component in `props`. Although it apparently can receive a prop as a fallthrough attribute from `GrandFather` in this case, it's preferable to explicitly provide it as `<GrandSon :client-id="clientId">` in order for it to not depend on a specific hierarchy of root elements.